# NullPointerException from Jboss LdapExtLoginModule

Tags: jboss, ldap

I am attempting to configure Ldap authentication for a Jboss web-app.  Jboss loads my module, but does not authenticate credentials that are known to be good.  I should point out that my module just extends LdapExtLoginModule without adding any logic.  I get the same error when defering directly to LdapExtLoginModule. The error:

PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required

is returned when I attempt to login.  I tracked the error down to a null pointer being thrown by a hashtable.put() operation in org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.constructInitialLdapContext.  Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:284)
    at com.alstom.auth.login.ldap.CustomLdapLoginModule.login(CustomLdapLoginModule.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.AbstractJaasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractJaasAuthenticationProvider.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at com.etse.security.SecureMethodAuthenticationManager.authenticate(SecureMethodAuthenticationManager.java:29)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:514)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.constructInitialLdapContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:742)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.createLdapInitContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:463)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.validatePassword(LdapExtLoginModule.java:340)
    at com.alstom.auth.login.ldap.CustomLdapLoginModule.validatePassword(CustomLdapLoginModule.java:152)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:281)
    ... 40 more
```

The function:

```
private InitialLdapContext constructInitialLdapContext(String dn, Object credential) throws NamingException
   {
       String protocol = (String)options.get(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL);
       String providerURL = (String) options.get(Context.PROVIDER_URL);
       if (providerURL == null)
          providerURL = "ldap://localhost:" + ((protocol != null && protocol.equals("ssl")) ? "636" : "389");

       Properties env = constructLdapContextEnvironment(providerURL, dn, credential);
       return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
   }
```

No hashtable.put() operations there so it must come from the InitialLdapContext constructor right?

```
public InitialLdapContext(Hashtable<?,?> environment,Control[] connCtls) throws NamingException {
        super(true); // don't initialize yet

        // Clone environment since caller owns it.
        Hashtable env = (environment == null)
            ? new Hashtable(11)
            : (Hashtable)environment.clone();

        // Put connect controls into environment.  Copy them first since
        // caller owns the array.
        if (connCtls != null) {
            Control[] copy = new Control[connCtls.length];
            System.arraycopy(connCtls, 0, copy, 0, connCtls.length);
            env.put(BIND_CONTROLS_PROPERTY, copy);
        }
        // set version to LDAPv3
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.version", "3");

        // Initialize with updated environment
        init(env);
    }
```

connCtls is null (see constructor call) so the only put operation is  env.put("java.naming.ldap.version", "3") which is obviously fine.

Any idea what's going on here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HashTable does not allow keys to be null. Verify that none of the keys you put into Hashtable env is not null. For example, for

```
 env.put(BIND_CONTROLS_PROPERTY, copy);
```

BIND_CONTROLS_PROPERTY must not be null.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

IMO, You have a code from another version of the `LdapExtLoginModule`. The correct one could be [this one on GitHub](https://github.com/picketbox/picketbox/blob/5cbd17781eb4cdd9f87f3a967cf9ffc875083083/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/jboss/security/auth/spi/LdapExtLoginModule.java#L742).

The code there is:

```java
private InitialLdapContext constructInitialLdapContext(String dn, Object credential) throws NamingException
{
   Properties env = new Properties();
   Iterator iter = options.entrySet().iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext())
   {
      Entry entry = (Entry) iter.next();
      env.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); /* this is the line 742 */
   }
```

So there seems to be a **login module option with null value**. Try to check your configuration.

*Please, share more details about your environment next time. It will help a lot to evaluate your problem. The most important details:*

- *application server **version***
- *used server **configuration** (i.e. configuration of the security domain in this case)*